# Resize underlying partitions in mdadm RAID1

Tags: ubuntu, ext3, mdadm

I have a home built NAS, and I need to slightly reconfigure some of my drive usage.

I have an mdadm RAID1 composed of two 3TB drives.  Each drive has one ext3 partition that uses the entire drive.  I need to shrink the ext3 partition on both drives, and add a second 8GB or so ext3 partition to one, and swap partition of equal size to the other.  I think I have the steps figured out, but wanted some confirmation.

1. Resize the mdadm RAID `resize2fs /dev/md0 [size]` where size is a little larger than the currently used space on the drive
2. Remove one of the drives from the RAID `mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1`
3. Resize the removed drive with parted
4. Add the new partition to the drive with parted
5. Restore the drive to the RAID `mdadm -a /dev/md0 /dev/sda1`
6. Repeat 2-5 for the other device
7. Resize the RAID to use the full partition `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 -z max`

Is there anything I've missed, or haven't considered?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you missed something very important and I've learned it the hard way. http://www.zdnet.com/blog/storage/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/162 points out that it becomes now statistically unavoidable to have bad sectors on the RAID array.

If you have a degraded RAID array and one of your drives hits a bad sector, mdraid will shut down the array. That will happen during the recovery when you re-add the drive, because every sector of the other drives needs to be read. I've spent quite a bit of time recovering from this, which is really tricky.\

What you should therefore do beforehand is:
`echo repair > /sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action`

(check https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Scrubbing)

Comment: I can't seem to run these commands even as sudo. I am running an ubuntu server. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: Too late for you, but to answer: The shell is running as you and sudo is not interpreting the redirection `>`. Either encapsulate everything in a subshell, or use `tee`. I prefer tee: `echo repair | sudo tee /sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action`

Comment: 1: The pointer to scrubbing is useful and appropriate; 2: It's 2018 now, 9 years past 2009. I'm operating several RAID5 arrays, of 5 8-10TB disks each, for several years now, and nothing bad has happened (apart from one of the enclosures dying...). I think the warning about RAID5 stopping to work was greatly exaggerated -- the chance of that happening is not as huge as made out to be, and can be further mitigated by paying attention to HDD error rate when you buy them; 3: You should still always have a backup of everything

Answer (score 3):

Your steps look good, with two exceptions:

1. After `resize2fs`, you need to shrink your mdadm array. E.g. do `mdadm --grow --size xxx` as step #1a.
2. I would also suggest doing all this while booted into a rescue CD, like [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/), and not while /dev/md0 is mounted. Follow the resize by fsck, just to make sure everything is ok.