# Ubuntu server remove extra partition and resize current larger in mdadm RAID1

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, raid-1, mdadm

I am running an Ubuntu Server. Currently, I have the hard drive configuration shown below:

[image: Hard drive config]

I want to remove the /mnt/winback partition and add the extra space to the /mnt/data partition. What is the best way to do this keeping the other partitions the same?

I have found the article here that shows how to shrink each drive:
[Resize underlying partitions in mdadm RAID1](https://superuser.com/questions/469117/resize-underlying-partitions-in-mdadm-raid1)
but would the steps be modified like this:
1. Resize the mdadm RAID `resize2fs /dev/md2 [size]` where size adds the additional space from /dev/md3
2. Remove one of the drives from the RAID `mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/sda1 && mdadm /dev/md3 --fail /dev/sda1`
3. Remove /dev/md3 from partition table
4. Resize the removed drive to occupy this extra space with parted
5. Restore the drive to the RAID `mdadm -a /dev/md0 /dev/sda1`
6. Repeat 2-5 for the other device
7. Resize the RAID to use the full partition `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 -z max`

Does the above seem right? I don't want to mess up my server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is unclear in your description: how can `/dev/sda1` be both in `/dev/md2` and `/dev/md3`? Also, is this RAID1? What devices make each array?

To give you an idea of a possible sequence of steps, I assume RAID1 in the following and that `/dev/mdX` is made of `/dev/sdaX` and `/dev/sdbX` (X={2,3}), and that `/dev/sdY2` and `/dev/sdY3` are contiguous on the disk (Y={a,b}).

General rule: when you shrink (whether on RAID or not), you need to shrink the filesystem first, then the partition; when you grow, you need to grow the partition first, then the filesystem.
So, in your case `resize2fs /dev/md2` is the very last step.

- You should start by unmounting `/dev/md3`.
- Then you need to fail and remove the devices (partitions) making up `/dev/md3`: `mdadm /dev/md3 --fail /dev/sda3 --remove /dev/sda3` (and same for `/dev/sdb3`).
- Then stop `/dev/md3`: `mdadm --stop /dev/md3`.
- Fail and remove `/dev/sda2`: `mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/sda2 --remove /dev/sda2`.
- Within, e.g., parted, you can remove `/dev/sda3` and extend `/dev/sda2` to occupy the unpartitioned space created.
- Add `/dev/sda2` back to `/dev/md2`: `mdadm /dev/md2 --add /dev/sda2`. Wait for it to resilver the newly added partition: `watch cat /proc/mdstat`; only when you get `[UU]`, move to the next step.
- Fail and remove `/dev/sdb2`, then remove `/dev/sdb3` and resize `/dev/sdb2`. Then add `/dev/sdb2` back to `/dev/md2` and wait for `[UU]` again.
- Grow the array: `mdadm --grow /dev/md2 --size=max`. Wait for `[UU]` again.
- Resize the filesystem: `resize2fs /dev/md2`.

Please check the man pages for `mdadm` and consult other sources. I am not responsible for any possible data loss.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes here but yes it is Raid1. /sda and /sdb make up each array. Also, I have read about making sure bad blocks are detected before doing the above using: repair > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_action. Is this recommended for the above?

Comment: THanks a lot. GOt it all sorted. Of note is I cound't remove both /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdb3 but removing one then caling stop everything worked fine.